# How does one include a javascript (widget) on a page created using the Textile markup language?

Tags: javascript, textile

The static page on my site can be edited and written using the textile markup language. Now if I need to include a GetSatisfaction widget or a Wufoo form on the static page, how do I go about it. Adding the widget code as it is doesn't help. Neither does the use of == in the string.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the platform in question? It'd help if I could try to figure out what Textile parser it's using.

Comment: Check github.com/jacobwg/spree-cms

Comment: I'm pretty busy right now, so I can't promise anything, but I'll try to make time to take a look at it some time in the next few days.

Comment: Thanks. Will wait for your response. Meanwhile, if I do find a solution I shall update it here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping it in `<notextile>these tags</notextile>` to temporarily suspend Textile parsing instead of using ==? That would probably be more likely to work, given how fragile == is in the face of embedded scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem got solved.

I used the notextile.. extended block and enclosed the JS code in a  tag.

Comment: You'll want to elaborate a bit on what you discovered the problem to be and then give your answer the "Best Answer" checkmark. Otherwise, you'll start building a bad accept rating and people will be less willing to answer your questions. I believe you also get some reputation points for handing out checkmarks and an accomplishment badge for your first self-answer.